# Oracle how to use array in where clause?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want store the value in array, and then use it in where clause.

Like this:

```
SELECT ... ... 
  FROM myTable 
 WHERE (myTable.id, myTable.type) 
    IN (SELECT * 
          FROM table(array_collection)
       )
```

array_collection value like this:

```
  (('1','N'),
   ('2','N'),
   ('3','Y'))
```

And there have any way not create schema level `table` type to do that?

Comment: Hey, can you please be more specific? How does 'table' look like?

Comment: If you don't want to create schema level type, I guess you should create function which will check your values and use it in WHERE filter predicate. But it won't have a good performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want store the value in array.

This is how you store value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE array_item IS object( id NUMBER, TYPE varchar2(3));

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE array_collection IS VARRAY(10) OF array_item;


declare
--Initialization 
var_array array_collection:=array_collection();
begin
  ---Storing 3 elements
 var_array.extend(3);
 var_array(1):= array_item(1,'N');
 var_array(2):= array_item(2,'N');
 var_array(3):= array_item(3,'Y');

 for i in 1..var_array.count
 loop
  dbms_output.put_line( var_array(i).id ||'    '|| var_array(i).TYPE );
 end loop;

end;
```

You can use as :

```
SELECT ... ... 
  FROM myTable 
 WHERE (myTable.id, myTable.type) MEMBER OF var_array ;
```

Comment: the last select is not correct: "MEMBER OF is not available with associative arrays and varrays."  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraarr.htm#JJDBC28574

Comment: Yes.. but its a Nested Table not Associative array.  Try my solution with type declaration.